# Flash Action Script count down timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I need to set a timer for 40mins, and after 40mins the frame should go to a specific frame. I have a code but it's format is 2400s this way. what i want is 40:00 this format. How do I change this code to that format. :)

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownHandler);
function  countdownHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{  
    countdown.text = 2400-myTimer.currentCount+"s remaining";
    if(myTimer.currentCount==2400){gotoAndStop(3626)}   
}
myTimer.start();
```

Comment: im interested in why you would need a timer for 40 minutes, quiet odd

Comment: @joshua more interesting is this little bit gotoAndStop(3626)

Comment: im creating a maths simulator... this countdown timer for mcq paper :) :)

Comment: @  The_asMan, yeah, lol 3626 frames is a movie....lol, BTW @user2214782 im very interested to the end result if your willing to show us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var s:String='';
var cdt:int=2400-myTimer.currentCount; // total seconds left
var mdt:int=cdt/60; // minutes left
cdt-=mdt*60; // seconds left
if (mdt<10) s+='0';
s+=mdt.toString()+':';
if (cdt<10) s+='0';
s+=cdt.toString();
countdown.text=s+' remaining';
```